# Python Selenium with Salesforce - Cannot Seem to Access Certain Form Elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, salesforce, frames

Using Selenium to try and automate a bit of data entry with Salesforce. I have gotten my script to load a webpage, allow me to login, and click an "edit" button.

My next step is to enter data into a field. However, I keep getting an error about the field not being found. I've tried to identify it by XPATH, NAME, and ID and continue to get the error. For reference, my script works with a simple webpage like Google. I have a feeling that clicking the edit button in Salesforce opens either another window or frame (sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology). Things I've tried:

1. Looking for other frames (can't seem to find any in the HTML)
2. Having my script wait until the element is present (doesn't seem to work)

Any other options? Thank you!

Comment: This question is missing minimal debugging details

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce's Lighting Experience (the new white-blue UI) is built with web components that hide their internal implementation details. You'd need to read up a bit about "shadow DOM", it's not a "happy soup" of html and JS all chucked into top page's html. Means that CSS is limited to that one component, there's no risk of spilling over or overwriting another page area's JS function if you both declare function with same name - but it also means it's much harder to get into element's internals.

You'll have to read up about how Selenium deals with Shadow DOM. Some companies claim they have working Lightning UI automated tests/ Heard good stuff about Provar, haven't used it myself.

For custom UI components SF developer has option to use "light dom", for standard UI you'll struggle a bit. If you're looking for some automation without fighting with Lighting Experience (especially that with 3 releases/year SF sometimes changes the structure of generated html, breaking old tests) - you could consider switching over to classic UI for the test? It'll be more accessible for Selenium, won't be exactly same thing the user does - but server-side errors like required fields, validation rules should fire all the same.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer! I figured it was something like this, but I just didn’t know how to search for it. 

Unfortunately, switching to classic is not an option for me, so I’ll need to read into Selenium/Shadow DOM and potentially Provar. Really appreciate this!